# Como chamar uma função que imprima o nome da função que a chama?

Tags: javascript, funções

Tenho a seguinte função:

```
function imprimir(id, nomeFuncao)
{
  console.log('id: ', id, 'Funcão que chamou: ', nomeFuncao)
}
```

Quero que a função `imprimir()` consiga imprimir no `console.log` as informações dessa chamada de função:

```
function criarEvento(id, oNomeDessaFuncao)
{
   imprimir(id, oNomeDessaFuncao)
}
```

Simulando a saída da função `criarEvento();`

```
(id: 23, Funcão que chamou: criarEvento)
```

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja imprimir, dê uma exemplo.

Comment: @bigown, quero que a função chamada imprima o nome da função que a chama.

Comment: A dúvida é porque segundo essa descrição isso não faz sentido `'Funcão que chamou: ', nomeFuncao`. Minha resposta inicial interpretou uma coisa (na verdade fiz a outra interpretação possível que parece ser a que você realmente quer).

Comment: e acertou na mosca.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode fazer isso:

```js
function imprimir() {
    console.log('Funcão que chamou: ', arguments.callee.caller.name)
}

function criarEvento() {
    imprimir(); //os argumentos são irrelevantes para o problema
}

criarEvento();
```

Usei o `arguments` porque apesar de ser obsoleto é aceito em todos navegadores.

A pergunta original não explicava bem o que queria e mesmo agora ainda dá margem para querer outra coisa que eu respondo originalmente:

```js
function oNomeDessaFuncao() {}

function imprimir(nomeFuncao) {
    console.log('Funcão passada: ', nomeFuncao.toString());
}

function criarEvento() {
    imprimir(oNomeDessaFuncao);
}

criarEvento();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Function/Name.js).

Answer (score 4):

Não é uma solução universal nem padronizada, mas alguns browsers aceitam:

```
function imprimir(id, nomeFuncao, frase)
{
  console.log( imprimir.caller )
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/bacco/pen/mrNgza)**.

Notar que ele retorna a estrutura toda da função. Precisaria de um parse. Tem outros métodos como o `arguments.caller`, considerado obsoleto pela documentação, mas pode ser interessante depende do contexto.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller